# HTTP 302 Redirect - Is this my problem?

Tags: network

I have an issue where my users are unable to access a particular web service (hosted app on AWS) because of an http 302 redirect pointing us to an incorrect port and address.

- It works ok from other networks.
- Packet capture on our edge firewall shows

  - the internal interface receiving the correct request
  - the external interface receiving the 302 packet from AWS server
  - the internal interface receiving the new and incorrect request as per the 302 redirect

edge firewall is a microsoft tmg server. Forgive me....I'm getting it replaced :)

Can anyone confirm whether or not I'm right in saying this is 100% out of my control and push back on the service provider? They think it's my firewall/proxy but since I can see the 302 packet coming in on the external interface I fail to see how.

Any other insights into how this could be occurring also appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you aren't answering the request with a 302, then, yes, hunt down whatever is and have it killed. This could be within your service(s) or upstream (DDoS service? CDN?)

Comment: When you say "within your services" what do you mean? The 302 is coming in on the external interface if the edge router....so there are none of my services running outside that.

Comment: @RickyBeam missed tag sorry

Comment: ...isn't the question then: "Why is this AWS instance sending a 302 to some queries?" ...and then that (configuring AWS) is off-topic here.

Comment: @CraigConstantine agreed. But that wasn't the question, the AWS instance is out of my control.

Comment: whether AWS is under your control is irrelevant; your ISP's network is out of your control, and we don't field questions about web services.  If you want to debate what is and isn't on-topic, please ask a question in [Meta]

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed that this redirect is originating outside my environment. Had my ISP run the same test.

Thanks all